# Does Oracle NoSQL Database cloud service integrate with Oracle Events and Notifications services?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

My team is currently running some tests with JSON documents in Oracle NoSQL Database cloud service. While the test is in progress, I would like to find out if the cloud service integrates with Oracle Events and Notifications services.

In our use case, new collections/tables may be added at any time when new incoming customer information requires to be stored separately for a particular business opportunity. There are microservices that consume such data for specific new marketing campaigns to customers. Once the campaign is over, the collection/table will be removed.

We would like to use Oracle Events and Notifications services to notify our sales team and downstream processes when a NoSQL collection/table is added or removed. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Service does integrate with Oracle Events and Notifications.  See this page for a list of events that are emitted by the Oracle NoSQL Database service https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/nosql-database/doc/nosql-database-cloud.html#CSNSD-GUID-BAF8A6C8-2F63-4B7E-982B-40DCD9D1635F